# g++ cannot change include path with -I

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

I'm on kubuntu using g++ 7.5.0 / GNU make for C++. My file structure:

```
bin
| .o files

header
|archiver.h

source
|main.cpp
|archiver.cpp

makefile
```

I want my source files to be able to detect header files without having to do #include "../header/archiver.h". I've tried using:

```
g++ -I/header
```

but this does not work. I get the error:

```
g++: fatal error: no input files.
```

makefile that was requested

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -c -Wall

objects = bin/main.o bin/archiver.o

all : $(objects)
    $(CC) -o build $(objects)

bin/%.o : source/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $?
    mv *.o bin

.PHONY : clean
clean : 
    rm -rf all $(objects)
```

Comment: You have the makefile. Why do you run `g++` instead of `make`?

Comment: Is `header` actually an absolute path residing in the root directory? Also there aren't any input files specified for compilation, as the error message says.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  if by that you mean the `header` folder sits in the root of the project, yes, it is .

Comment: @273K please explain. I'm not running g++ compiler commands, I'm just trying to change the include directory.

Comment: @RylanYancey `root of the project` isn't the same as ***root-directory***!

Comment: `/header` means on the root of your OS filesystem you have a header folder. I wouldn't expect that. The / at the beginning means an absolute path not a relative path.

Comment: @RylanYancey _"I'm just trying to change the include directory."_, you'll need to adapt your makefile accordingly, and call `make` as mentioned.

Comment: It's unclear where `g++ -I/header` is. If you run `make`, then show the content of makefile instead of describing your attempt that looks like running `g++ -I/header` in the Terminal.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you are correct, I see that. still, g++ -I/home/ryancey/Cpp/mpi_ringmapping/header does not work.

Comment: @273K I've edited my post to include the contents of the makefile.

Comment: Now show how you want `#include` instead of how you dont want do it

Comment: @273K As I stated in my question, "..without having to do #include "../header/archiver.h".   I wanted to only have to use "#include "archiver.h"", which I now have working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
g++ -I<header-dir>
```

doesn't change any default settings for the `g++` include search paths with subsequent calls, as you seem to assume.

You'll need to pass that compiler flag for each individual c++ call, which are issued by `make` according the rules defined in your `makefile`.
The latter is what you need to adapt, best using a pre-defined makefile variable like `CXXFLAGS` or `CXXINCLUDES` (check the GNU-make documentation for details).

---

For your specific case

```
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -I./header
```

should work.

Comment: This was it. I did not realize that I had to put the . in -I./header .

Thank you so much, I have been banging my head against this rock for too long.  new to C++/make.